# mass update Users using button or user invoked other than data loader

Tags: user-management

is there a way to add a button on User list view to mass update? or is there way to mass update update set of users when needed?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot add custom button on users list, you will need to achieve this through  apex + Visualforce page / lightning component.